# Python -- calling a function in same file as a class from within an instance of that class?

Tags: python, class, scope

I have a file structured like this:

```
imports

def myFunc(spam):
    etc

class MyClass():
    def someMethod(self):
         myFunc(eggs)
```

I don't think this works as I understand that functions assume scope local to just that function.  How would I accomplish this?  It seems silly to import itself and then call imported.myFunc()

In case there are those that need to know why -- this is a file called utilities and the class is Database that contains my database wrapper stuff.  Outside of it are utility functions.  I'd prefer to keep Database inside of utilities, if possible.

Comment: What happened when you tried? Hint: it works fine.

Comment: I guess I could have put some effort into trying it out -- the immediate code was actually an exception so it wasn't as simple as just running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of a given identifier is determined by the location of its definition.  myFunc is defined at the file level, so it is visible within someMethod since it is in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call any function outside your `Class` with the normal function call (as you have it in `someMethod`).

If you prefer to have the function inside your Class as a method, the call would then be `self.myFunct(...)`.